# Angular create dynamic extended components

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have multiple forms that I would like to display to the user (one at a time). I would like to be able to dynamically create these forms from multiple components. Each of these forms share some common code / template parts, as well as common "save" and "cancel" functionality.

I have been able to create dynamic components and insert them into the current view, but I am confused on how to dynamically create a component that extends another component.

Please see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/container-practice?file=src/app/app.component.ts) where I have a `generic-form-component`. This generic form component would extend one of the example forms (`apples-form` or `oranges-form`)

When you click on a button for an "Apples" or an "Oranges" form, I want the form to be displayed inside of the "generic-form" html.

I hope the stackblitz is simple enough to describe my issue. I feel like I am close, I simply do not understand how to contain the specific form template within the template of the generic form.

lines 27 and 28 of `app.component.ts` can be switched out to display either the generic-form or the selected form from the button press.

Comment: I am working on a project and if you want to enter https://blizoomen.web.app and select Cambridge city and click on the elements that appear if that is what you are looking for we can talk. all navigation except login and register occur in the same parent component

Comment: @TomaszVizaint are you dynamically creating components and placing them in the view? I would be interested to see your approach

Comment: I preparing this simple example how is constructed my page https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zwzcc2?file=src/app/app.component.html. If something is not clear to you, do not hesitate to ask